# OpenCV cannot read AVI/MP4 file. [mpeg4 @ 0x55935a6280c0] get_buffer() failed

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to read single frames from an mp4 file using open-cv in Python

```
video_path = 'test.mp4'
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

success,image = cam.read()
count = 0
while success:
    success,image = cam.read()
    print('Read a new frame: ', success)
    count += 1
```

The success boolean instantly evaluates to false when trying to read the first frame. These are the errors I'm getting:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x55935a6280c0] get_buffer() failed
[mpeg4 @ 0x55935a6280c0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[mpeg4 @ 0x55935a6280c0] get_buffer() failed (-12 (nil))
[mpeg4 @ 0x55935a52bd80] Too many errors when draining, this is a bug. Stop draining and force EOF.
```

I can convert files from mp4 to avi and avi to mp4 using ffmpeg in my terminal. It also shows no signs of the files being corrupted. The code still doesn't work when trying to read an mp4. I have 20GB of RAM so I don't think it is a RAM problem.

Python 3.6.13, opencv-python 3.4.18.65. Using Linux

Edit: Restarting machine and changing from 20GB RAM to 40GB sometimes fixes it. Considering its a 17 second file only a few MB big this doesn't seem to make sense?

Comment: maybe you should use newer `Python` (ie. 3.11) and the newest `opencv-python` (4.8.1)

Comment: `while success` should be `while cam.isOpened():`

Comment: Instead of using `cv2.CAP_FFMPEG`, try initializing the `VideoCapture` without specifying the backend, like `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)`. Sometimes, letting OpenCV choose the backend automatically resolves the issue.

Comment: I am limited in the Python version i can use because of other dependencies. I've tried not specifying the backend and while cam.isOpened() doesn't do anything except iterate over Null frames since it can't find any frames for some reason.

Comment: have you tried other videos? have you inspected that video with any other program that reads videos?

Comment: Yes, tried multiple videos and they also work in normal video playback, as well as when running ffmpeg

Comment: so what can be concluded? that *this one video* is broken?

Comment: The other videos work in playback, but not opencv. I assume it's an issue with the opencv library and memory stuff that can't be fixed without changing versions.

Comment: you could provide one such video for investigation. also `print(cv.getBuildInformation())`